# How to print same clusters in matrix with their coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

Hi guys I have a  matrix like this:

```
INPUT=[[1 0 2 2 0] [0 0 2 0 2] [2 2 2 2 2] [0 2 0 2 0] [0 0 3 0 0]]
```

I expect to see same cluster with their coordinates like this:

`OUTPUT=[[(0, 0)], [(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 3)], [(4, 2)]]`.

`[(0, 0)]` Refers 1's at first and its A one group.

```
[(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 3)]
```

Refers all 2's in matrix.

I wanted to list all of the clusters  based on their coordinates as my example.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
INPUT=[[1, 0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0]]
clusters = {}
for i, row in enumerate(INPUT):
    for j, x in enumerate(row):
        if x in clusters:
            clusters[x].append((i, j))
        else:
            clusters[x] = [(i, j)]

OUTPUT = []
maxi = max(clusters.keys())
for i in range(maxi):
    OUTPUT.append(clusters.get(i, None))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: With this code we cant see highest number cluster. With this input we cant see 3's group in our output.Actually we dont want to see group of 0's .Thank you

Comment: for i in range(1,maxi+1): just changed this line and works thank again!